# Why is _AppDomain prefixed with an underscore? Seriously, it bugs me that it is always in my field intellisense

Tags: c#, .net

Whenever I write a new class and add some internal fields, I use an underscore prefix like so:

```
private readonly int _foo;
```

Why did the .NET team decide to create an AppDomain interface with the name _AppDomain? It just bugs me to see it whenever I type an underscore to get my class level fields in intellisense. Why isn't it IAppDomain or something else?

Yes, I am very picky... I know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That interface exists [for this purpose:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system._appdomain.aspx)

> Exposes the public members of the `System.AppDomain` class to unmanaged code. This API is not CLS-compliant.

So I would imagine that as such there were more relaxed naming conventions for this type.  It is hard to say *why* this was done though but the type most certainly does not conform to the Framework Design Guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Such interfaces are made to interact with COM environment. e.g. you can find `_Exception` interface.